# When do I need to check the origin property?

Tags: javascript, security, javascript-security

When do I need to check the `origin` property on events that implement the [`MessageEvent`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/comms.html#the-messageevent-interfaces) interface in order to avoid security vulnerabilities?

> The origin attribute must return the value it was initialized to. It represents, in server-sent events and cross-document messaging, the origin of the document that sent the message (typically the scheme, hostname, and port of the document, but not its path or fragment).

This property is exposed by server-sent events, Web sockets, cross-document messaging, channel messaging, and broadcast channels.

What should I know? What do I need to beware of? What should I keep in mind?

What scenarios would it make sense to check the `origin` property?

Do I even need to check `origin` at all, or just the `isTrusted` property?

```
var websocket = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org/');
websocket.onmessage = function(e) {
  // Can I trust this event?
  // Do I need to check e.origin?
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When do I need to check the origin property?

Best practise: **always**.

> What should I know? What do I need to beware of? What should I keep in mind?

Whenever you are communicating with some other party, that party might be hostile. Depending on what the communication is about, that can be a security issue, especially if you a) share data b) act on requests - which is pretty much always.

The point is that *any* party can try to initiate communication with you, and even if you initiated it, in the case of cross-document messaging (frames, tabs etc) and channels your counterpart may change (by navigation, by forwarding). You should explicitly check whom you are communicating with and whether you want that.

To cite [MDN on `postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage):

> *If you do not expect to receive messages from other sites, do not add any event listeners for message events. This is a completely foolproof way to avoid security problems.
>
>   If you do expect to receive messages from other sites, always verify the sender's identity using the origin and possibly source properties. Any window (including, for example, http://evil.example.com) can send a message to any other window, and you have no guarantees that an unknown sender will not send malicious messages. Having verified identity, however, you still should always verify the syntax of the received message. Otherwise, a security hole in the site you trusted to send only trusted messages could then open a cross-site scripting hole in your site.*

> Do I even need to check origin at all, or just the isTrusted property?

No, the [`isTrusted` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) does something entirely different. Also, the browser cannot know which domains you trust and which not, especially when you want to do cross-origin messaging.

Comment: If I register a event listener for the 'message' event on my websocket instance, can my event handler receive events that are not from itself?

Comment: I think on web sockets and server-sent events you can omit the check if you trust the endpoint. Not sure how `.origin` works in case of redirects there.